# Hibernate different type pojo mapping

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a problem with a mapping for this structure that i designed

```
public abstract class A<T> {
 private int discriminator_value = -1;
 private T value;
 //...
}

public class One extends A<String> {

 public One(){
  setDiscriminatorValue(1);
 }
 //...
}

public class Two extends A<BigDecimal> {

 public Two(){
  setDiscriminatorValue(2);
 }
 //...
}

public class Three extends A<Date> {

 public Three(){
  setDiscriminatorValue(3);
 }
 //...
}


public class TheTargetSolution {
  private Long info1;
  private Long info2;
  private Long info3;
  private A targetPojo; 
 //...  
}
```

**The table structure**

```
 THE_TARGET_SOLUTION_TABLE
  - INFO_1   NUMBER(10)
  - INFO_2   NUMBER(10)
  - INFO_3   NUMBER(10)
  - DISCRIM  NUMBER(2)
  - TEXT_A   NVARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
  - NUMBER_A NUMBER(10)
  - DATE_A   DATE
```

The main thing is that we need to have in TheTargetSolution the targetPojo that is type of A class and this class does not have mapping, (we need more info to entity and thees is no option to do this using relation many to many in this case all data has to be stored in one table) that is instance of type that apply to discriminator.

**Resuming**

When the DISCRIM column value is 1 the targetPojo should by type of One

When the DISCRIM column value is 2 the targetPojo should by type of Two

When the DISCRIM column value is 3 the targetPojo should by type of Three

Any suggestions ?

Comment: are you using xml, or annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical scenario for [inheritance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/inheritance.html), with table-per-class-hierarchy. If you use xml, see the linked docs. If using annotations, use

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCRIM", discriminatorType=INTEGER)
public abstract class A {
   // properties here
}
```

And then

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Two extends A<BigDecimal>
```

Comment: Yes, and no. The condition what is messing here is that the class A can't be mapped, and should somehow be used as component. This because the data that will be used in A are form several table (different meaning of them) And when use table-per-class hierarchy i will have to redesign all logic in database

Comment: See the `@MappedSuperclass`. I don't know the xml equivallent, but this means A does not have a serpate table. Anyway, I can't see your whole database in order to make better judgement

Comment: This might work for annotation notation of hibernate, but i don't found any equivalent for XML, nevertheless this can be accepted. Thank You for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/candybon/fasttrack
it provide a solution that cooperate all the pojo into one table

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.